# File.exist? の引数が nil だった時に nil または false を返す方法

Tags: ruby

`File.exist?`でファイルの存在確認をするときに引数が`nil`の可能性があれば

```
File.exist?(filename) if filename
```

と書いているのですが、`try`に近い形で`filename`が`nil`なら`nil`を返し、`String`であれば`File.exist?`の処理を行う定番の書き方はありますか？

自分でメソッドを定義する必要があるのであれば現在の書き方を維持していこうと思っているのですが
より良い書き方があるなら知りたく質問させていただきました。

`active_support`のような使えるメソッドをまとめて読み込む形の物も採用していこうと考えています。

Comment: `File.exist?(filename) if filename`は単独では(File.exist?の例外を利用するのでなければ)無意味なコードですが、実際にはどのように利用されているのでしょうか。後置ifなので分岐の条件式では無いと思いますが、結果を変数に保存して後で利用しているのですか？

Comment: あくまで事前にfilenameが`nil`でないことをチェックしてるのを示したかっただけですので状況によりけりですが`if filename.present? && File.exist?(filename)`のような使い方をしています。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

定番の書き方はわかりませんが、

```
File.exist?(filename.to_s)
```

とすれば `filename` が`nil`でも`String`でも存在チェックが実行できます。

```
> File.exists?(nil)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
    from (irb):1:in `exists?'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
> File.exists?(nil.to_s)
=> false
```

ちなみにもし、true/false/nilの3種類を区別して返したい、という場合はその背景まで含めないと適切な回答がしにくいです。（何か特殊なことをやろうとしているのかもしれません）

通常はfalse/nilはどちらも偽として扱われるので、わざわざ区別するのはレアケースだと思います。

Comment: 質問が不明瞭でしたね、すいません。`nil`と`false`を区別して返す必要はありません。`.to_s`で変えてしまえば良いことには気づきませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

かなり前の自分の質問への回答になるのですが今同じ処理を書くとすると`filename`変数に`Pathname`を使い、

```
filename.try(:exist?)
```

とします。このページを見た人の参考になればと思い書いておきます。

Answer (score 2):

後置ifでなくifの条件式の話であれば、

```
if !filename.to_s.empty? && File.exist?(filename)
```

と書きます。filenameが空文字でないことが文脈上明らかか想定しなくてよいのであれば

```
if filename && File.exist?(filename)
```

とします。

後置ifなら(File.exist?は例として不適切なので)

```
do_something(filename) unless filename.to_s.empty?
```

とかでしょうか。どちらにしても、多少冗長になってもfilenameのチェックをしているという意図を明白にする方を選びます。

`File.exist?(filename.to_s)`や`do_something(filename.to_s)`だと

- `#to_s`がnilよけであること
- メソッドが空文字を許容するかどうか(nilだった場合に空文字を渡すことは意図した動作なのか)

がコード上明白でないので私なら避けます。逆に言えばそれらが明白である場面ならそう書くかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

いろいろやりようがありそうです。どれにするかは好みによると思います。
自分なら以下のどちらかでやります（多分最初の）。
なおこの辺の構文は結合法則がややこしかったりするので、結果を代入に使ったりするなら全体をカッコで括ったほうが確実です。

`filename && File.exist?(filename)`
`filename ? File.exist?(filename) : nil`

なお質問の内容にもう少し合わせるならこういう感じでしょうか。異常時に`filename`が`nil`であることを期待できるならここまでする必要はありませんが。

`filename.is_a?(String) ? File.exist?(filename) : nil`